# Smoke came out of my Macbook Pro, and now it displays a folder with a question mark

Tags: macbook-pro

This is bizarre. So I was sitting working on my Macbook Pro (Retina, late 2013 IIRC), the laptop is on the edge of the armrest of the sofa I am sitting on. The Macbook Pro tips forward slightly but I catch it, so it doesn't fall. However that  very instant the screens goes black, but the computer is still on. By the top right I see a little puff of smoke come out. It's so faint I think I've hallucinated it, but I take a look and as I move in closer there's an undeniable burning smell. I turn the laptop off. I try to turn it back on, and it does turn back on, but all it displays is a blinking folder with a question mark. I try booting it in recovery mode (holding down option) but the only available option is Internet Recovery and the Disk Utility claims that there is only about 1.2 GB of space on the whole computer (in total).

I don't understand how my laptop fried itself when all I did was tip it forward about 15 degrees. How is that possible? Can I salvage it?

Comment: What if the failure was coincidental to external events? I could see dust being dislodged by an acceleration but not electrical effects. Every plane or train would be causing  “poof” if this were a thing.

Comment: @bmike I know, which is why this event seems so outlandish to me. So you're saying the smoke/burning was just bad luck, and it happened to coincide with the laptop getting tipped over?

Comment: It’s bad luck since something burned, but I wouldn’t attribute it to the near fall. It just failed at the same moment.

Comment: there is an old joke that says that computers run on smoke and if you let the smoke out they stop working. Unfortunately it sounds like a component used that moment to fail in a rather catastrophic way. I would take the Mac into a repair shop or Apple store and have them look at it. No doubt a component in the Mac is fried (literally...) and needs to be replaced. That the Mac will boot into recovery mode indicates that it might not be the system board and might be repairable.